# Que tamaño debería tener aproximadamente un logo en SVG?

Tags: svg

Hice un logo en Illustrator que es de apenas 3 palabras y decora una flor, de todas la formas que lo he guardado como SVG pienso que este pesa mucho, ya que me da entre 170 y 185KB.

Lo he convertido a curvas, al ser un svg con tan poco contenido no deberia pesar menos, estaré haciendo algo mal?, gracias

Comment: Por favor comparte el código de tu svg para verificar si se puede optimizar.

Comment: Adicionalmente te sugiero cambiar el título a **Optimizar un svg para reducir su peso** ya que tamaño se puede interpretar como sus dimensiones.